# Handling Out of Office and/or Pulling Out of Office from Outlook

Tags: outlook

We are looking to provide an Out of Office (OoO) behavior in Salesforce. This is primarily to allow other to see when people are not in and to bounce any tasks, etc. that are assigned to them.

Currently we make an OoO image available and request users switch to it as their profile image when out of the office. This is not ideal.

Ideally we would like to sync the OoO detail from Outlook as this is where most people remember to set it.

Any one found a good solution to OoO or synching to Outlook.

Comment: There's an existing idea for it - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqyuAAC You may want to up vote this for consideration

Answer (score 2):

Exchange Server does not directly integrate with Salesforce.

For similar problem, our solution is -

Develop a .NET based bridge application which
- Can be contacted by Salesforce using REST WebService 
- uses EWS to connect to Exchange Server. 
- Host this application on a server with Public IP.

At a specific event, SF evokes appropriate web service to connect to the application, pass email id of the user whose OOO status is to be checked. The application evokes EWS methods to connect to Exchange Server & check OOO status....response flows back in reverse sequence.